# Using try-catch between multiple routines

Tags: c#, error-handling, try-catch, system.reflection

This is somewhat of a follow up to a previous question I had asked, although I am now able to provide a lot more code to improve my question and further show my trouble with this area.

I have three routines here. Two of these routines work together - and if successful, will load an assembly into memory using System.Reflection. I would like for these routines to return an error if the file did not load properly into memory, but for some reason these try-catch statements simply will not work the way I would like.

**Note: For this routine to work the file must be a .net assembly. If, for example, the file was programmed in VB6 an error will be thrown. This is the error I am trying to have returned to me.**

```
private void ExecuteDataIntoMemory(string filePath)
{

    byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);

    try
    {
        ExecFile(bytes);
        MessageBox.Show("successfully loaded this file into memory");
    }

    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Could not load this file into memory");
    }

}

private static void ExecFile(byte[] data)
{
    try
    {
        //Work around for "SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault"  
        System.Threading.Thread T = new System.Threading.Thread(ExecFile);
        //Set STA to support drag/drop and dialogs?
        T.SetApartmentState(System.Threading.ApartmentState.STA);
        T.Start(data);
    }

    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("caught some error ...");
    }

}
private static void ExecFile(object o)
{

        System.Reflection.MethodInfo T = System.Reflection.Assembly.Load((byte[])o).EntryPoint;
        if (T.GetParameters().Length == 1)
            T.Invoke(null, new object[] { new string[] { } });
        else
            T.Invoke(null, null);


}
```

I can clarify more if necessary but I'm not sure what other information to include at this point.

Comment: The message `MessageBox.Show("Could not load this file into memory");` will never succeed because you are calling `catch {MessageBox.Show("caught some error ...");}` in the `ExecFile` method so you have to call `MessageBox.Show("caught some error ..."); throw;` to rethrow the exception and so can be catch in the `ExecuteDataIntoMemory` method.

Comment: The problem is that my code is returning back to the 'ExecuteDataIntoMemory' void BEFORE the error even occurs in the execFile void ... Get what I am saying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you well, You want the `ExecuteDataIntoMemory` to be evaluated only if the `ExecFile` succeed.

1- You are running a new thread to execute the `ExecFile` method which will be executed in a different thread. So first at the `try` block in `ExecFile(byte[] data)` run the `ExecFile(data)` without a new Thread because you want to wait for it any way:

```
try
{
    ExecFile(data);
}
```

2- Notice that you have two method with the same name 'ExecFile(byte[] data)' and `ExecFile(object o)` the data you are passing is from type `byte[]` so it will be infinite recursive or till stack over flow exception is raised. So you should cast `data` to object and then pass it to the method i.e:

```
try
{
    ExecFile((object)data);
}
```

3- At the `catch` block of the ExecFile(byte[] data) method rethrow the exception so it can be handled from the caller method two i.e:

```
try
{
    ExecFile((object)data);
}
catch
{
    MessageBox.Show("caught some error ...");
    throw;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the "throw" statement within the catch statement of ExecFile to raise the same "exception" (or error) caught in ExecFile.  For example:

```
 catch {
      throw;
 }
```

I think I figured out the problem though.  ExecFile(byte[]) starts the thread and returns immediately without waiting for the thread to exit.  To allow that method to wait for the thread to exit, add:

```
 T.Join();
```

right after starting the thread.  (To avoid possible ambiguity, however, you should rename ExecFile(object).  I'm also not sure whether ExecFile(byte[]) will catch the exception from ExecFile(object).)

Comment: I have tried this ... but it does not return anything. I urge you to give this a go within your own application to see what I mean.

Comment: Sorry.  I assumed (mistakenly) that it would work this way _in this context_, that is, in a different thread from ExecuteDataIntoMemory (it wasn't clear from the question).  In general, however, throwing an exception will allow that exception to be caught in the calling method.

Comment: No, not a problem! I'm just very surprised how much of a problem this simple task is causing me...

Comment: I have been at this problem for nearly four hours now .. haven't moved from my computer ... you solved it! Thank you!

Comment: If caller method should wait for the finishing of the thread, why even do it in another thread? Just call it like a normal method.

Answer (score 0):

If you catch the Exception in `ExecFile(byte[] data)` it won't be propagated in your parent method (`ExecuteDataIntoMemory(string filePath)`), and then won't be catched again

If you really need to catch your exception twice, rewrite your child method this way

```
private static void ExecFile(byte[] data)
{
    try
    {
        //Work around for "SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault"  
        System.Threading.Thread T = new System.Threading.Thread(ExecFile);
        //Set STA to support drag/drop and dialogs?
        T.SetApartmentState(System.Threading.ApartmentState.STA);
        T.Start(data);
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("caught some error ...");
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

If not, simply not `try..catch` errors in this method, and the Exception will be propagated..

Comment: Once again, the message box in 'ExecuteDataIntoMemory' is returning a "success" BEFORE an error can even be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Just look in the callstack which method call the ExecuteDataIntoMemory method again?

if you are using Visual studio IDE put a breakpoint at the messagebox:

```
   MessageBox.Show("successfully loaded this file into memory");
```

then simple go to the view menu, from there find the callstack window to display and look at the callstack (show external code to the callstack)

maybe this could help.

Answer (score 0):

1. The rough way (I think), but should work in your case, is subscribe to

   AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException

event riased, which will get the exception raised directly from the function `ExecFile(object o);`

1. Or create a state machine which is set to NEGATIVE state in case of any exception in  `ExecFile(object o);` method.
2. Or just do not do it in multithreading :)